# Quickest way to calculate the limit

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

I am looking for the simplest and quickest method to calculate the limit of sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$ where $$a_n=\frac{1^2}{n^3}+\frac{3^2}{n^3}+\frac{5^2}{n^3}+\ldots+\frac{(2n-1)^2}{n^3}$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well if you need a limit of sequence then doing [Stolz-Cesaro](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stolz%E2%80%93Ces%C3%A0ro_theorem) would be the best
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{1^2+3^2+5^2+\cdots+(2n-1)^2}{n^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(2n-1)^2}{n^3-(n-1)^3}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{4n^2-4n+1}{3n^2-3n+1}=\frac{4}{3}$$

Comment: why $n^3-(n-1)^3$ but not $(n+1)^3-n^3$? and at the top why not $(2n=1)^2$

Comment: Well I like using $n$ and $n-1$ instead of $n+1$ and $n$ but you can as well write $\frac{(2n+1)^2}{(n+1)^3-n^3}$

Comment: you're right i did not notice that

Answer (score 2):

Note
$$ \lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{2k-1}{n}\right)^2=\lim_{n\to\infty}4\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{n}\left(\frac{k-\frac12}{n}\right)^2=4\int_0^1x^2dx=\frac{4}{3}.$$

Answer (score 0):

it's not hard to prove (by induction, for example) that
$$
1^2+3^2+5^2+\dots+(2n-1)^2\ =\ \frac{n(2n-1)(2n+1)}{3}
$$

Comment: then my question is what is the easiest way to find out this formula

Answer (score 0):

Following @larry01 you get that
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{4n^2-1}{3n^2}=\frac{4}{3}
$$

Comment: The limit is $4/3$ not $4$.

Comment: Forgot the 3. Thanks